# Does Windows 10 have brute force protection against an attack from its local network?

Tags: windows-10, networking, security, brute-force

Say, we have two machines on a local network:

- Machine A is malicious and is trying to access userdata on Machine B.
- Machine B runs Windows 10 Pro with "Network discovery" turned on. The latter means in particular that anyone on the network can see Machine B's hostname and if Machine A knows a user's username and password, it can access that user's home directory:

  [image: Enter network credentials]

Does Windows 10 Pro have any built-in protection against Machine A brute forcing its way in?

Comment: Use a strong password so that brute forcing is impractical

Comment: I'm trying to find the reference post/tweet that I saw a month ago, but the summary was "we're finally adding auth failure delays to SMB in Win11/Server2022" because apparently they did not have any before.

Comment: @Leo - Remember that in any Domain (normally 5 users or more), Network Discovery is ON.  While some users have weak passwords, any decently strong password makes it entirely unworkable to brute force. My own Windows machine password would take over 200,000 years to brute force.  ....    https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-an-8-character-password-could-be-cracked-in-less-than-an-hour/

Comment: You should create an account lockout policy (even possible without using domain accounts). These lock the account after x wrong pw tries. These settings can be configured  settings can be configured in the following location in gpedit.msc at Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Account Lockout Policy.